# Difference in quoted shipping and charged shipping

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, shipping

I am using Magento ver. 1.9.0.1 and shipping_override.  However, the problem existed before the addition of shipping_override (and after).

The system gets UPS rates using my UPS account.  However, the checkout always shows about 6% LESS on any selected rate.  When logged in viewing the shopping cart you can see BOTH amounts.

This has nothing to do with the tax rate, or shipping_override.  The flat rates from shipping_override are also reduced and I've tested with no-tax states.  There is no added charge setup (either fixed or percentage).

Its a mystery. . .

Answer (score 1):

MORE:

It DID have something to do with the tax rate.  I found a shipping.php that subtracted the tax from the shipping. . .

HOWEVER, The problem was in configuration in two places.  I had to create a shipping tax object in SALES/TAXES and change SYSTEM/CONFIG/SALES/Tax to listing my state as the Default State, and display everything without tax except including it in the grand total. . . and possibly some other things.

Anyway. . . I think I have it fixed.  I've run a dozen or so taxed and not taxed sales and all is good so far.  All I can say is that forms in Magento are way too complicated. . .  Set them up, wait a couple days and do them again. And maybe AGAIN.  You will see something to adjust each time.